# Quais os motivos para migrar uma aplicação para uma tecnologia mais recente

Tags: java, c#, angularjs, jsf, primefaces

Gostaria de saber de vocês oque acham disso? 
Quais os benefícios?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse tipo de pergunta é offtopic para o site, mas segue visão abaixo.

Como você mesmo disse, o maior problema não é a tecnologia (JSF) e sim como os componentes e classes de negócio foram programados. Independente de você escolher java, .net, php ou qualquer outra linguagem, se você não tiver conhecimento de como tirar o melhor proveito dessas tecnologias sem abrir mão do mvc/mvvm, continuará fazendo software de baixa manutebilidade. Você também precisa ter equipe que esteja disposta a fazer as coisas com qualidade e dentro de um padrão proposto, quantos de nós já não vimos algum programador relaxado que colocando if dentro de um controller ?

É importante saber que ao sair do JSF você perde um pouco da produtividade que o desenvolvimento com componentes proporciona, mas ganha do outro lado por ter backend orientado a action, que é mais fácil de assimilar para programadores com pouca experiência.

Angular com WebAPI teria uma arquitetura um pouco diferente da Asp.net MVC.

Nos dias atuais, não consigo ver sistemas grandes serem entregues com qualidade sem o uso de técnicas como TDD & DDD.